# @svgr/webpack not working with css background image on webpack

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, styled-components

I am trying to import an SVG using @svgr/webpack and css background property but it just removes the background property all together.

I have this on webpack:

```
import { babelLoader } from './loaders'

export const svgReactComponentRule = {
    test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    issuer: /\.[jt]sx$/,
    use: [
        babelLoader,
        {
            loader: '@svgr/webpack',
            options: {
                babel: false,
                icon: true
            }
        }
    ]
}

export const svgRule = {
    test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    issuer: { not: [/\.[jt]sx$/] },
    type: 'asset/inline'
}

export const svgRules = [svgReactComponentRule, svgRule]
// Eventually I add this as module rules for webpack config
```

Then  I import the svg:

```
import Logo from '@images/logo.svg'
```

If I add the Logo directly on the JSX it all works put but if I do it with css the background property disappears from the document on render.

```
export const LogoWrapper = styled.div`
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(${Logo}) no-repeat center / cover;
`
```

I am using version `"@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0"`

Answer (score 0):

I turns out that the `Logowrapper` needed to be done on a `ts` file instead of a `tsx` file otherwise it would not load according to the `issuer`